# Don't change color of parent element if child element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here's my HTML:

```css
.imageURL:active .image_submit_div {
  background-color: #ccc;
  /* has no effect */
}

.image_submit_div:active {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_div">
  <label for="id_image" class="image_submit_div">
        <h3>+ add file</h3>
        <input id="id_imageURL" class="imageURL" type="text" name="imageURL" />
    </label>
  <input id="id_image" type="file" name="image" />
</div>
```

The parent div is `image_submit_div`. When you click on it, it changes color:

The child element is `.imageURL`. When this is clicked, I don't want the parent div to change color. When I do the following code, it has no effect:

So how do I prevent the parent div from changing color when I click the child div?

EDIT: Here is a code snippet to give you a better perspective: https://codepen.io/kingdezz/pen/WOoPgY

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense. Could you edit your question to show a working snippet of the issue, along with a clear statement of what you're trying to achieve. Also, what does this have to do with JS/jQuery?

Comment: _"The child div is imageURL"_ - you mean the div that is not a div but an input …?

Comment: Yes it is an input not a div, my mistake. Will edit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS you can't style a parent depending on it's child ( or an event on that child ) . You can't do things like `child:hover parent { styles }` .

Css only works from top to bottom `parent:hover child { styles }`.

Your question is a bit unclear but you could use JQ for this

you can use `mousedown` and `mouseup` events to achieve what you want

```js
$(".imageURL")
  .mousedown(function(e) {

    $(this).parent(".image_submit_div").addClass("colored")

  })
  .mouseup(function() {
     $(this).parent(".image_submit_div").removeClass("colored")
  });
```

```css
.image_submit_div:active {
 background-color:red;
}
.image_submit_div.colored { 
background-color:blue;
}
.image_submit_div { 
display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image_div">
  <label for="id_image" class="image_submit_div">
    <h3>+ add file</h3>
    <input id="id_imageURL" class="imageURL" type="text" name="imageURL" value="i don't trigger click on parent" />
  </label>
  <input id="id_image" type="file" name="image" />
</div>
```

Comment: Ok I'm using your second example. It is weird, when I use: `$(".imageURL").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parent(".image_submit_div").css({
    "background-color": "#e6e6e6"
  })

});` the first time I click on the imageURL, the parent div changes color. But every other time after that it works fine. Any idea why?

Comment: try it now in the snippet

Comment: But the parent div has to change color when you click on that aswell. Also when I say change color, I mean `:active` so not change color permanently. Here is my code snippet: https://codepen.io/kingdezz/pen/WOoPgY

Comment: @Zorgan so let me understand. When you click on parent div, you want to change it's background color. When you click on input, you want also to change the background color of parent div , but a different color, right ? I edited my answer. let me know if this is what you want and i will explain further

Comment: Your edited answer works perfect, thankyou very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery [.focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) and [.blur()](http://api.jquery.com/blur) events like,

```js
$(function() {
  $('#id_imageURL').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).closest('label').css('background', '#ccc');
  }).on('blur', function() {
    $(this).closest('label').removeAttr('style');
  })
});
```

```css
.image_submit_div {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  width: 55%;
  height: 320px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  margin: 0 0 25px;
}

.image_submit_div:active {
  background-color: #ededed;
}

.imageURL:active .image_submit_div {
  background-color: #ededed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image_div">
  <label for="id_image" class="image_submit_div">
        <h3>+ add file</h3>
        <input id="id_imageURL" class="imageURL" type="text" name="imageURL" />
    </label>
  <input id="id_image" type="file" name="image" />
</div>
```